# FluentNHibernate override generic class

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

How to override the mapping of generic class?
I have this class:

```
public abstract class TranslatableEntity<TTranslation, TEntity> : Entity
{
        public virtual String Name { get;set; }

        // ...
}
```

And I whant to do this:

```
public class TranslatableEntityMap<T> : IAutoMappingOverride<TranslatableEntity<T>>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<TranslatableEntityMap<T>> mapping)
    {
        mapping.IgnoreProperty(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

How can I do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK It is not possible. More over it has no sense to map generic class sice mapping requires the real class with implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to map generic classes with NHibernate.